# How to tell which pthread wakes up the pthread? C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm currently working on a multithread programming. I have a few customer pthreads and two clerk pthread (A and B). Each customer pthread has a unique id, arrival_time, and service_time. The customer pthreads are initially sleeping and wait to be awake by clerk thread. My problem how can i find each customer thread is awaken by clerk pthread A or clerk pthread B?

Thanks

Comment: Just use a message queue, and have message contain clerk id? Hard to say without seeing code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pthread conditional variable mechanism. Instead of using sleep to customer thread just use `pthread_cond_wait()` and wake up by your clerk thread.